# Anyone know how to fix this 403 - Forbidden error when trying to view my lighttpd info.php file?

Tags: php, php-fpm, lighttpd

I'm working on a lab project for one of my cybersecurity classes and am getting an error message where one shouldn't be. We are using `lighttpd` and I also installed these packages:
`php`, `php-cgi`, `php-mysql` and `php-fpm`.

I then created an `info.php` file containing:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

The `lighttpd` localhost page loads fine, as seen below, but `localhost/info.php` does not.

`lighttpd` localhost loads fine:
[image: lighttpd localhost loads fine]

`localhost/info.php` gives error 403:
[image: localhost/info.php gives error 403]

Comment: What is the output f `ls -l php-info` in the http root dir ? And what user is running th webserver ?

Comment: @SorenA The resulting output is as follows: ls: cannot access 'php-info' no such file or directory. I'm running as an administrator.

Comment: @matigo The name of the file is 'info.php'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo lighty-enable-mod fastcgi`

`sudo lighty-enable-mod fastcgi-php`

`sudo systemctl restart lighttpd`

Fixed this problem on my system.